# backup SQL Server 2012 wit batch / SQL files

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-2012, database-backups

I have multiple database in my Microsoft SQL Sever and I want to create a batch file that will create a backup of all database once launced. I'm trying to learn the basis studying online tutorials, but I'm stuck. The files are:

1) SQLCMD_BACKUP.bat. I used . since the database is local, and the instance name. The code is the following:

```
SQLCMD -S .\m2248 -i Query_Backup.sql
```

2) The SQL file, called Query_Backup.sql. I tried to use multiple commands, since there are multiple databases:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [database1] TO  DISK = N'C:\inetpub\Backup_MSSQL\backup-database1.bak' WITH INIT, NAME = 'database1-backup’, DESC = ’Backup database1 - Completed', SKIP, CHECKSUM;
BACKUP DATABASE [database2] TO  DISK = N'C:\inetpub\Backup_MSSQL\backup-database2.bak' WITH INIT, NAME = 'database2-backup’, DESC = ’Backup database1 - Completed', SKIP, CHECKSUM;
```

What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `BACKUP DATABASE ... NAME = 'database2-backup’, DESC = ’Backup database1 - Completed' ...` -- you have different types of apostrophies here, note that `'` (right) is not the same as `’` (wrong)...

Comment: For future reference, don't make people guess. Provide the complete error message you receive and tell people exactly how and when you encounter it.

Comment: based on the comment provided by @aschipfl you could therefore delete this question as it is merely a syntax issue.

Comment: The problem is, I have no errors report: after launching the bat file, the cmd window closes without results. Moreover, I don't know why but  in the original documento there is no syntax error, it happens only pasting the code here. I double checked and rewritten the code from scratch, but still no result.

Comment: @Dan_Hero, to get the error messages, specify - `-o` to direct the output to a file or add a `PAUSE` command at the end of the bat file so you can see STDOUT and STDERR in the console window before it closes.